# How to install gapps on anbox for linux

Tags: linux, android-emulator

I want to install gapps on Anbox. Below is a screenshot of Settings, about device. [image: Screenshot from Anbox Settings, about emulated device]

I'm hoping to find out what version of gapps should be used.

Comment: Is your anbox a snap?

Comment: @karthiknair I run both  snap based and non snap based Anbox

Comment: You should be able to get the Androdi device info by executing `adb shell getprop`. As far as I know Anbox should be a fork of Android x86, so most likely is is an x86_64 or x86 platform.